# How to check linux kernel version number?

Tags: linux, kernel

Is there such a command out there?

Comment: You should search your "subject" directly on google. 
so you wouldn't wait for an answer.

Answer (score 13):

For more info:

```
uname -a
```

If you're interested **only** in version number:

```
uname -r
```

Answer (score 5):

This is almost a superuser question...

`uname -r`

Answer (score 3):

```
uname -a
```

Gives me:

Linux tom-sl500 **2.6.32-22-server** #33-Ubuntu SMP Wed Apr 28 14:34:48 UTC 2010 x86_64 GNU/Linux

The bold bit is the kernel version number

Comment: See also: `man uname`